# Laravel : Specific route throttle

Tags: laravel, caching, laravel-9

I want to use a specific throttle for a website route that sends an email to the user (email validation).
I've used `middleware("throttle:3:1")`, but the problem is when a user moves in the website, it increases the global throttle, so it looks like it has to wait 1 minute before being able to refresh and get the email.

I've tried to set up a dedicated middleware as proposed by ChatGPT, but not working.

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
    $throttle = 5; // 5 requests per $ttl (60 seconds)
    $ttl = 60; // 60 seconds ttl

    $key = sprintf('throttle_CustomValidateEmail:%s:%s', $request->ip(), $request->path());

    if (Cache::has($key) && Cache::get($key) >= $throttle) {
        return abort(429);
    }

    Cache::increment($key, 1, $ttl);

    return $next($request);
}
```

In fact, it's working but will never decrease, so if the user refreshes the page too many times, he will definitely be stuck.

How can I handle this problem?

Comment: If you need to have a rate limit per user you shouldn't need custom middleware. Check https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#defining-rate-limiters specifically you can do something like `Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->user()->id)` or `Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->ip())` and then use that named limiter

Comment: Thanks for your comment !
I will look deeper on this !

Comment: Update, it works. For people who wants to use it, you need to use `->middleware("throttle:emailSend")` on your route. Then define a new call in your RouteServiceProvider `configureRateLimiting()` `RateLimiter::for('emailSend')`